# Is there anything like AXML for iOS?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

In Android, you lay out a view with an AXML file, where you specify the hierarchy of sub views and their relationships, and the OS loads this file and renders the view.

In iOS, there's a NIB file, which is similar in concept, but it's completely **human unreadable** (in my opinion).  You can create this file with the WYSIWYG editor in Xcode, but you can't just type it by hand, because it's immensely complex and impossible to get right.

I find the WYSIWYG editor unwieldy for any but the most trivial layout, and so I'm also finding that in iOS, it's easier to build the control tree in code than to use the NIB file.  But the AXML approach seems much easier still.

So, I'm wondering if there's any iOS library that would let me lay out the code in a declarative way (that is, not with a designer), and then create a view from that, with automatic resizing and other conveniences.

Comment: [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML), [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets)

Comment: what makes you say it's immensely complex coding without nibs? All you need is to know your coordinates and asset sizes.

Comment: Xamarin has their own iOS Designer in Alpha now, as an alternative to using the XCode designer.  I personally just do my UI in code.  But the short answer to your question is "No".

Comment: What prevents you to do the view hierachy and layouting by code in your implemenentation files?

Answer (score 2):

The .storyboard format is a simpler format to read, use that instead of XIB files.

Answer (score 0):

It seem like you are coming in iOS development from Android.

But Editing background XML (Back Source) view file is not style of iOS.

Yes you can see that file but Apple want that you design your app by using this two approach only.

How I can say that? Because apple have not provided any document for how to do that (At least I have not come across any).

1. Design in visual editor (XIB Or Storyboard)
2. By Using code (Create view and controls and addSubview)

Mostly we use mix approach we use top level and simple design by first one and use detail and complex design by second one.

Storyboard is new and very good one try to use that.